# I was reading a linear algebra book when I came across a statement that confused me. Help me if I misunderstood anything.

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

A book that I'm reading stated "let $V$ be a vector space and let $D$ be a nonempty subset of $V$. Let $M$ be the collection of all vectors in $V$ which can be expressed as a linear combination of some finite subset of $D$. Then $M$ is a subspace spanned by $D$."
To my understanding(I believe the confusion is here) $D$ should be collection of independent vectors. What I understood was that any subset of the null space of a vector space can be expressed as the linear combination of finite subset of the null space that are linearly independent to one another. For example if $X^1=(1,1,0)$ and $X^2=(0,1,1)$ then a subset of the null space $X$ can be expressed as $X=aX^1+bX^2$ where $a$ & $b$  are real numbers.
But then the book continues to prove that $M$ is a subspace by concluding $0$ is a linear combination of finite subset of $D$ but last time I read a set containing the zero vector can't be linearly independent. I'm pretty sure that I have misunderstood a concept, I just dont know what mistake I have made.

Comment: if the vectors are dependent, there are many ways to express a target vector as a linear combination.  Still, this span is a vector subspace.

Comment: @WillJagy yes i know that it must be a subspace but the book formerly stated that if you pick $X$ and $Y$ such that both are linearly independent to one another then any vector in the null space is dependent on them. what is the need to state this if any vector can do the job? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what book are you talking about?

Comment: @WillJagy Linear algebra By Paul C. Shields

Comment: Showing that the 0 vector is in the span of D does not mean 0 is in D itself. In fact, the 0 vector is in the span of any set of vectors, and establishing that is part of the proof that such a span forms a subspace (the first property/axiom of a vector space is that it contains 0). But even if D were not linearly independent, or even if it did contain the 0 vector, that does not matter. Its span is still a vector space in its own right.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thank you!